# I have imported a font with both Latin characters and glyphs to my css stylesheet, how do I make the glyphs show up instead of the Latin Characters?

Tags: html, css

I'm building a webpage and want to incorporate a "toki pona" font that will display glyphs for the corresponding words. Whenever I attempt this, only the Latin characters also included with the font show up. It does however, work in Microsoft Word.

The css code I have included is what I have already tried.

```
CSS:

@font-face {
font-family: 'linja_pona_otfregular';
src: url('linja_pona-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
     url('linja_pona-webfont.woff') format('woff');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}

#philosophy{
font-family: linja_pona_otfregular;
font-feature-settings: "philosophy" 3;
}


HTML:
<h1 #philosophy>tomo</h1>
```

Comment: `<h1 #philosophy>tomo</h1>` should be `<h1 id="philosophy">tomo</h1>`

Comment: @LelioFaieta I have fixed that portion, but the glyph is still not showing. Any idea where I go from here?

Comment: There is an error in `font-feature-settings`: those setting names always have 4 letters. No exceptions.

Comment: Where did you get the font from? The only version I can find online is an OTF version.

Comment: What browser are you using? Some browsers I tested need some extra settings for the icons to show up, such as Edge; it needs `font-feature-settings: "liga";`